# Finding How Many Hours Between Two Dates Without Using DateTime

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I've written a code like that but it's giving me an error. I shouldn't use DateTime code by the way.

```
aylar = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def countLeapYears(d):     
    years = d.y
    if (d.m <= 2):
        years -= 1
    ans = int(years / 4)
    ans -= int(years / 100)
    ans += int(years / 400)
    return ans

def getDifference(dt1, dt2):
    n1 = dt1.y * 365 + dt1.d
    for i in range(0, dt1.m - 1):
        n1 += aylar[i]
    n1 += countLeapYears(dt1)
    n2 = dt2.y * 365 + dt2.d
    for i in range(0, dt2.m - 1):
        n2 += aylar[i]
    n2 += countLeapYears(dt2)
    return (n2 - n1)

class Tarih:                         
   def _init_(self, d, m, y,s): 
     self.d = d                           
     self.m = m
     self.y = y
     self.s = s
     
tarih1 = Tarih(1, 12, 2021,0)
tarih2 = Tarih(4, 12, 2021,23)
farkgun = getDifference(tarih1,tarih2)

if (tarih1.s > tarih2.s):
    farkgun = farkgun-1
    tarih2.s = tarih2.s+24

print("Iki tarih arasindaki fark: ",farkgun,"gun.")
print("Iki tarih arasindaki saat: ",(farkgun*24)+(tarih2.s-tarih1.s),"saat.")
```

And the error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    ratih1 = Tarih(1, 12, 2021, 0)
    
TypeError: Tarih() takes no arguments
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with that code?

Comment: Always include the complete error traceback as **text**, not image.

Comment: Typo: `__init__` lacks its underscores.

Comment: I tried to write it as text, but it gave an error while sharing because it perceives it as a code. I had to add an image.

Comment: "shouldn't" isn't "mustn't", so I'd use it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you made a typo here

```
class Tarih:                         
   def init(self, d, m, y,s):
```

In python you should declare constructor with `__init__` function

```
class Tarih:                         
   def __init__(self, d, m, y,s):
```

Comment: I fixed it but it still gives the same error.

Comment: @Satasha Seems, like you add only one `_` symbol. You should add two underscores both sides `__init__`

Comment: @Satasha here a working example https://pastebin.com/DiDacySc

Answer (score 1):

You have put only 1 '_' for the `__init__` function.

It works on my machine:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just replace `def _init_(self, d, m, y, s)` with following:
`__init__(self, d, m, y, s)`

**you need 2 underscores on each side**